# Google App Engine handler won't work unless a catch all handler is set

Tags: google-app-engine, handler, app.yaml, google-app-engine-php

I'm struggling to setup URL handlers in the `handlers` section of my `app.yaml` file for my standard engine php application.

Following code makes both `mydomain.com/abc.php` and `mydomain.com` display the `abc.php` file in my `dist` folder:

```
handlers:
- url: /(abc\.php)
  script: dist/abc.php

- url: /(.*)
  script: dist/abc.php
```

However, I don't want a catch all handler, so I removed it so only 1 handler exists:

```
handlers:
- url: /(abc\.php)
  script: dist/abc.php
```

Now when I go to `mydomain.com/abc.php`, I'm getting a 500 error:

[image: 500 error]

How can I make a targeted URL work on GAE without using a handler for all URL's?

Comment: What is the error you see in your logs?

Comment: I had a look at the StackDriver Logging but I can only see requests to /_ah/start + some createVersion logs - no specifics on the php error. Any advise on how I can see PHP errors?

Comment: From [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#handlers_element) it says that the _patterns are evaluated from top to bottom_. You initially had URL pattern A, and URL pattern B. When having only A, it is not working. I would say that your requests were handled through pattern B; A failed and they moved on to B. I am not sure yet why... appart from the previous docs, you lack the `$`, the [end anchor](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html#aswift_1_anchor)

Comment: I've created 2 separate projects to make sure old handlers weren't reused/cached, so I don't think that's the issue. I've setup a 3rd project following your suggestion:
`handlers:`
`- url: /abc.php$`
`script: dist/abc.php`
this also results in the same 500 error as before.

Comment: I took the [simplest code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-php-guestbook/tree/phase0-helloworld) and reproduced your handlers. And it works. Moreover, I get 404s (not 5XXs) when I hit bad URLs, if I don't have a catch all handler. A difference I can think about is the custom domain, which I lack. Also, regarding logs, you should be able to see both `activity` and `request_log`. If no requests are logged, it means that the requests are not resolved and directed towards your app. Try w/o the custom domain, to eliminate one factor.

Comment: I used the same helloworld example, and I'm using it without a custom domain. If you'd like more information about the exact setup, check out the issue in the GAE issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/74469001

Comment: thanks for sharing the issue tracker link. If you get a solution via that channel I kindly ask you to provide a response here as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My app.yaml file contained resources:

```
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 1
  disk_size_gb: 10
```

Since this isn't supported by the App Engine Standard environment, simply commenting out this code resolved the issue.